# How can I use Python's webbrowser.get within a docker container

Tags: python, docker, python-webbrowser

So I have been trying to use `webbrowser.get` from within my Docker container but it is failing to find a browser to launch.

I believe there are two ways to do this:

- mount the location of my current browser within my container and point the environment variable BROWSER at it
- download a browser within my container and use that

So far I've been trying to go with the ladder because I think its more full-proof when handing my Dockerfile over to others.

This is what I have so far but it continues not to find the browser:

```
# set base image (host OS)
FROM python:3.8

ENV CHROME_VERSION "google-chrome-stable"
RUN sed -i -- 's&deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main&#deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main&g' /etc/apt/sources.list \
  && apt-get update && apt-get install wget -y
ENV CHROME_VERSION "google-chrome-stable"
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
  && apt-get update && apt-get -qqy install ${CHROME_VERSION:-google-chrome-stable}

RUN set -eux \
  ; . /root/.bashrc
```

Then I just try running

`docker exec -it [container id] python`

and running the code

```
import webbrowser; 
webbrowser.get('http://google.com')
```

but it just continues to return `False` and not open a browser.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `webbrowser.get()` to get the browser, or even simply `webbrowser.open("http://example.com")` to use the default browser? If that still won't work, that would be a different question anyway. Your current usage messed up with the 2 different APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers are a headless environment. You can't open a graphical browser like Google Chrome because there is no screen to run graphical applications!

You can create a virtual screen buffer, like using `xvfb`, or use text-based browsers instead, but you shouldn't expect to be able to open a browser on your docker *host* system outside of the container.